# Foundation 5 Project Installation Fails

Tags: terminal, zurb-foundation, failed-installation

I've followed the steps on the Getting Started with SASS page to install Foundation 5 and the required components.

I am now trying to install Foundation into a project folder, via Terminal (i.e. Foundation new myProject).

Terminal returns a long list of errors that I've pasted in below.

No idea what this issue could be -- any ideas are greatly appreciated.

List of directories inRuby/Gems/1.8/gems/:

```
chunky_png-1.3.3
compass-1.0.1
compass-core-1.0.1
compass-import-once-1.0.5
ffi-1.9.6
foundation-1.0.4
multi_json-1.10.1
rb-fsevent-0.9.4
rb-inotofy-0.9.5
sass-3.4.9
thor-0.19.1
zurb-foundation-4.3.2
```

The errors:

```
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
                run("gem install compass", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                   ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:44: Can't assign to true
                run("gem install compass", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                         ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
                run("gem install compass", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
    ...  run("rbenv rehash", capture: true, verbose: false) if whic...
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:45: Can't assign to true
    ..."rbenv rehash", capture: true, verbose: false) if which("rbe...
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
    ...hash", capture: true, verbose: false) if which("rbenv")
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
                run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                               ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:94: Can't assign to true
                run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                     ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
                run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                              ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:97: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
              run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                             ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:97: Can't assign to true
              run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                   ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:97: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
              run("compass compile", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                            ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:114: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
          option :libsass, type: :boolean, default: false
                                ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:115: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
          option :version, type: :string
                                ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:127: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
    ...one #{repo} #{name}", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:127: Can't assign to true
    ...repo} #{name}", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:127: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
    ...ame}", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:130: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
              run("bower install", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                           ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:130: Can't assign to true
              run("bower install", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                 ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:130: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
              run("bower install", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                          ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:132: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
              run("git remote rm origin", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                  ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:132: Can't assign to true
              run("git remote rm origin", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                        ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:132: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
              run("git remote rm origin", capture: true, verbose: false)
                                                                 ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:149: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
          option :version, type: :string
                                ^
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:159: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli.rb:2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/foundation-1.0.4/bin/foundation:3
        from /usr/bin/foundation:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/foundation:19
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious reason that I was overlooking is the Ruby version. The Foundation docs state Ruby 1.9+ is required, and I had only Ruby 1.8 (running OS X 10.8.5).